# ZWJ (‍Zero Width Joiner) sequence emoji showing as 2 emoji

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, emoji

I am trying to create a bash script where I can print a ZWJ emoji. I can't seem to figure it out, nor find much info online as to why it is now working as intended.

Example bash script

```
echo "test zwj emoji ‍"
```

Running this script on Intellij IDEA's embedded terminal, both with Zsh and Sh shows :

[image]

However, in iterm2 or the default mac terminal as well as in the editor of Intellij, things seem fine :

[image]

I have tried to get the emoji both from [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/woman-astronaut/) as well as the Mac emoji keyboard. Both result in the same outcome.

Could it be that Intellij IDEA's terminal does not support Zero Width Joiners? Or am I using it in the wrong way?

I have tried with a few of the examples [listed on emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-zwj-sequence/) but none seems to be supported so far.

Comment: I think I have found a similar issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2523